# Why is translateZ(xpx) not working even though perspective is set?

Tags: css, parallax

I want to build a parallax effect with pure CSS3 and even though I used "perspective: 1px;" on my parent element, "transform: translateZ(-1px) scale2;" is not working. The IDE I am operating on is Intellij. Can Anybody help?

```
body {
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 1px;
}

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: inherit;
    width: 100vw;

}

header h1 {
    margin-top: -100px;
}

header,
header:before {
    background: 50% 50% / cover;

}

header::before {
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("../../assets/paralax/landscape.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    transform-origin: center center 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale2;
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Can we get a full [mre] please? We need to see your HTML

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to see exactly what CSS is and what CSS isn't being applied. For a start you have scale2 not scale(2) in a transform. That should be showing an error when you look at that element.

Comment: The "scale(2)" instead of "scale2" fixed the problem. Thanks you guys!